# Uncompleted Summation Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have run across a problem that requires me to find the sum of a "geometric" series up to the $20$th iteration, starting at $n=1$. The series is given as follows:

$$S(n) = 1 + 1.1 + \dots$$

So far I have found a pattern that can be used for each next iteration of the series. I am assuming that each piece of the series is $\frac{11}{10}$ of the last piece.

$$1\\
1.1\\
1.21\\
1.331\\
1.4641\\
1.61051\\
\cdots
$$

And so on. Although I could continue this pattern for as many iterations as necessary, I wanted to find a way to calculate this series with a single equation, either in sigma notation or in function form.

Comment: Did you Google geometric series?  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) has a formula for the finite sum

Comment: @RossMillikan In the equation [http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/4/7/4/47470196f9edbc3b7bb81e853a3487ff.png](Sum of the first n terms of a geometric series), How would you change the expression if the limit was changed to "n" and the base was changed to "k=1" instead of "k=0?"

Comment: The variable is a dummy-it doesn't matter if it is $k$ or $n$.  If the lower limit is $1$ instead of $0$, you need to correct.  So $\sum_{k=0}^7 f(k)=\sum_{k=1}^8 f(k-1)$  You should write this out (every term) with $f(k)=k$ to see what is happening.

Comment: @RossMillikan So the series could be represented by $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {\frac{11}{10}}^{k}$?

Comment: Yes, if is a true geometric series.  You have scare quotes around geometric and only two terms, so I am not confident.  If so, the terms after $1.21$ should be $1.331, 1.4641, 1.61051, \dots$  Your continuation is also reasonable, but you have not defined clearly what happens after the tenth term when you have to worry about carries.  It is not a geometric series, though.

Comment: @RossMillikan You're correct, I took down incorrect terms, I'll make sure to fix the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're unfamiliar with the [formula for geometric sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), you could solve it in this way:

$$\begin{align*}S &= 1 + 1.1 +1.1^2 \dots+1.1^{19}\\S-1 &= 1.1 + 1.1^2 +  \dots + 1.1^{19}\\\frac{S-1}{1.1} &= 1 + 1.1 + \dots+1.1^{18}\\\frac{S-1}{1.1} &= S -1.1^{19}\\S-1 &= 1.1S - 1.1^{20}\\(1.1-1)S &= 1.1^{20}- 1\\0.1S &=1.1^{20}-1\\S&=10\times 1.1^{20} - 10 \approx 57.2749995\end{align*}$$

---

If you are familiar with the formula, like you've noted $a = 1$ and $r = 1.1$, so the sum to the $20$th term is $$S = \frac{1(1-1.1^{20})}{1-1.1} = 10\times 1.1^{20} - 10$$

---

Note that the first term is $1 = 1.1^0$ and in general the $n$th term is $1.1^{n-1}$ and so the $20$th term is $1.1^{19}$